# Getting Response from TCP server on Swift client

Tags: xcode, sockets, tcp, swift, gcdasyncsocket

I am trying to write a TCP socket client in swift using GCDAsyncSocket, but I have one problem. In my code I have a NSTextField (called box) and here is my code:

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate 
{

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var box: NSTextField!

    var bsocket: GCDAsyncSocket!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?)
    {
        bsocket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
        var port:UInt16 = 8090
        if (!bsocket.connectToHost("localhost", onPort: port, error: nil))
        {
            println("Error")
        }
        else
        {
            println("Connecting...")
        }
        var request:String = "Arn.Preg:3302:"
        var data:NSData = request.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        bsocket.writeData(data, withTimeout: -1.0, tag: 0)
        bsocket.readDataWithTimeout(-1.0, tag: 0)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification?) 
    {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    func socket(socket : GCDAsyncSocket, didReadData data:NSData, withTag tag:UInt16)
    {
        var response = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("Received Response")
        box.stringValue = box.stringValue + "\n" + response
    }

    func socket(socket : GCDAsyncSocket, didConnectToHost host:String, port p:UInt16)
    {
        println("Connected to \(host) on port \(p).")
        box.stringValue = box.stringValue + "\n" + "Connected to \(host) on port \(p)."
    }
}

func socket(socket : GCDAsyncSocket, didReadData data:NSData, withTag tag:UInt16)
```

When I use the telnet command in the terminal to try to access my TCP server, this is the result.

```
Marzuk:~ marzukrashid$ telnet localhost 8090
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Arn.TipoSer:XPL0:
```

Then, when I type in "Arn.Preg:3302:", the server returns this:

```
Marzuk:~ marzukrashid$ telnet localhost 8090
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Arn.TipoSer:XPL0:
Arn.Preg:3302:
Arn.Resp:3302=329351:
```

When I type in "Arn.Preg:3302:" the server returns "Arn.Resp:3302=329351:", this is the result I am trying to achieve, I want the NSTextField in my application to display "Arn.Resp:3302=329351:". Right now, when I run my code, the program logs "Connecting...", "Connected to 127.0.0.1 on port 8090.", and "Received Response", as it should, and in the NSTextField in the application itself, it displays "Connected to 127.0.0.1 on port 8090." and "Arn.TipoSer:XPl0:" as it should, but it is not displaying "Arn.Resp:3302=329351:" as I want it too.

My question is why is my code not doing this, and how can I fix my code into doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the code, I just edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have learned that the didReadData function only runs when the readDataWithTimeout function is run, so I added the readDataWithTimeout function to the didConnectToHost, didReadData, and applicationDidFinishLaunching. I learned that a "\n" is required at the end of the request to give the return keystroke used in the terminal, so I added "\n" to the "Arn.Preg:3302:" to make it "Arn.Preg:3302:\n". The final code looked like this:

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var box: NSTextField!


    //let bsocket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: AppDelegate.self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
    var bsocket: GCDAsyncSocket!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?)
    {
        bsocket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
        var port:UInt16 = 8090
        if (!bsocket.connectToHost("localhost", onPort: port, error: nil))
        {
            println("Error.")
        }
        else
        {
            println("Connecting...")
        }
        bsocket.readDataWithTimeout(-1.0, tag: 0)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    func socket(socket : GCDAsyncSocket, didReadData data:NSData, withTag tag:UInt16)
    {
        var response = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("Received Response")
        box.stringValue = box.stringValue + "\n" + response
        bsocket.readDataWithTimeout(-1.0, tag: 0)
    }

    func socket(socket : GCDAsyncSocket, didConnectToHost host:String, port p:UInt16)
    {
        println("Connected to \(host) on port \(p).")
        box.stringValue = box.stringValue + "\n" + "Connected to \(host) on port \(p)."
        bsocket.readDataWithTimeout(-1.0, tag: 0)
        sendRequest()
    }

    func sendRequest()
    {
        var request:String = "Arn.Preg:3302:\n"
        var data:NSData = request.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        bsocket.writeData(data, withTimeout: -1.0, tag: 0)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you're trying to send the `Arn.Preg:3302:` message and get a response before you've actually connected. In your `applicationDidFinishLaunching` you initiate an asynchronous connection and then immediately call `writeData` and `readData` -- you probably need to do something like:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate 
{

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var box: NSTextField!

    var bsocket: GCDAsyncSocket!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?)
    {
        bsocket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
        var port:UInt16 = 8090
        if (!bsocket.connectToHost("localhost", onPort: port, error: nil))
        {
            println("Error")
        }
        else
        {
            println("Connecting...")
        }
    }

    func socket(socket : GCDAsyncSocket, didReadData data:NSData, withTag tag:UInt16)
    {
        var response = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("Received Response")
        box.stringValue = box.stringValue + "\n" + response
    }

    func socket(socket : GCDAsyncSocket, didConnectToHost host:String, port p:UInt16)
    {
        println("Connected to \(host) on port \(p).")
        box.stringValue = box.stringValue + "\n" + "Connected to \(host) on port \(p)."

        var request:String = "Arn.Preg:3302:"
        var data:NSData = request.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        bsocket.writeData(data, withTimeout: -1.0, tag: 0)
        bsocket.readDataWithTimeout(-1.0, tag: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but after trying this, the result was the same. I also tried moving the request to the didReadData function, but that didn't work either.